# How mux two mp3 and video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I try this command to mux two mp3's with mp4 video, but it's not working - no sound:

```
ffmpeg -i first.mp3 -i second.mp3 -i video.mp4 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest -c:a libmp3lame out.mp4
```

It's working with aac encoder. But i want lame. How properly achive this task?

Comment: Please show the complete console output from your `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Sorry for long responce. http://pastebin.com/RfVfwhvb  It's working with `libfdk_aac`